# How do I write test in Go that make use of the -short flag and can it be combined with the -benchmark flag?

Tags: unit-testing, go, benchmarking

How do I make use of the `-short` flag given in `go test -short`?

Is it possible to combine the `-short` and `-benchmark` flags?

I am quite new to the Go language but I am trying to adapt myself to some of its common practises.  Part of this is to try and ensure my code has not only Unit Tests added in a way that the `go test` system works but that `go test -benchmark` also functions in a useful manner.

At the moment I have a benchmark test that includes a series of sub-tests based on varying sized of input data.  Running the 15 permutations takes a long time, so it would be nice to given an option of shortening that test time.

The next set of tests I plan to write could include a series of data input examples.  I expect running a single one of these could work as a sanity check for a short test but having the option to run several on longer (or normal) test runs would be good.

When I look at [the GoLang documentation for the testing flags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags) it says "Tell long-running tests to shorten their run time." which sounds like what I want, but I cannot work out how to pick up this flag in the test code.

Comment: `if testing.Short()`.

Comment: And no: To shorten your benchmarks use -benchtime command line flag instead of short.

Comment: @Volker thank you for explaining where the -short flag is hiding and for the recommendation to use -benchtime as well.  Could you give your answer as an answer?

Comment: I really wish downvotes came with a mandatory why.  I show resurch evidence, what I am asking is clear enough that I got a helpful response within minutes and I would say it is useful as the standard go documentation (linked to) gives no clue how you use -short in tests, just that some tests somewhere do. Feedback would be helpful.

Comment: The best advice for questions like this is: Read the full package documentation. Most likely it is there. Searching in a package documentation often is helpful too. E.g. the term "short" occurs 7 times in https://golang.org/pkg/testing/ and almost each occurrence is helpful to your question. With Go this advice really is more helpful than e.g. with other languages where class documentations often are nonexistent or useless.

Comment: Web searches also tend to be helpful. I put go test short into Google and the first result was the doc Volker linked, which explains how to use it, and the second was a blog post which also explained exactly how to use it.

Comment: Looks like my mistake was looking at the Testing_flags documentation which does not link or make reference to the package documentation.  Being new to Go I did not realise that the Documents area of the site was not where you needed to go for documentation.

Comment: @Adrian the problem with Google Search is that it shows you pages based on what you have visited so you get to see that page in the results because you have been there or been to a site with that page linked before.  What I get is lots of links for personality tests and looking for short circuits in electrical connections. Hopefully it will learn I am interested in Go language topics soon too.

Comment: Try golang instead of go, it helps sometimes with searches. An anonymous search for golang test short gave me similar results, so it's not a search personalization issue.

Comment: I'm not new to Go, and I still have a hard time understanding the documentation (or even memorizing which address I should look the documentation at since there are like 3 places that seem to be the "official" Go documentation). This particular case is even weirder because there's the link that the OP provided, which totally throws him of the correct track. But at any sign of weakness, the professional downvoters will smell it and come here to "help".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How do I make use of the -short flag given in go test -short?

Using the short flag on the command line causes the `testing.Short()` function to return `true`.  You can use this to either add test cases or skip them:

```
if testing.Short() == false {
    // Extra test code here
}
```

The above is perhase a little unusal, it may be more common to see:

```
func TestThatIsLong(t *testing.T) {
    if testing.Short() {
        t.Skip()
    }
}
```

Be sure to have enough test cases for your `-short` runs to do at least a bare minimal check.  Some people suggest using the `-short` run for the main continuous integration and pre-commit checks while keeping the longer test runs for scheduled daily or weekly builds or merges.

The [Documents section of The Go Programming Language site](https://golang.org/doc/) mentions how to write test code briefly but the bulk of information about the topic is in the [Package Documentation for the Go Testing Package](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/).  For most topics, the majority of documentation will be found in the package rather than separate.  This may be quite different from other languages where the class and package documents are often poor.

---

> Is it possible to combine the -short and -benchmark flags?

It is possible as the `testing.Short()` is global in scope.  However, it is recommended that Benchmark tests do not make extensive use of the `-short` flag to control their behaviour.  It is more common for the person running the benchmarking to alter the `-benchtime` permitted for each benchmark test case.

By default, the benchtime is set to one second.  If you have 60 benchmark test cases, it will take at least sixty seconds to complete the run (setup time + execution time).  If the benchtime is set to less:

```
go test -benchmem -benchtime 0.5s -bench=. <package_names>
```

the overall execution time will go down proportionality.

The various testing clags are described in the [go command documentation's Testing Flags section](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags) (not the package documentation which does not mention benchtime).  You do not need to do anything different in your benchmark code to have the benchtime be effective, just use the standard `for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {` and the framework will adjust the value of N as needed.

Although it is not recommended, I have used `-short` within a benchmark to reduce the number of test cases when varying input to a function to give an indication of its [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).  For all benchmark runs (-short and normal), I keep a representative data size for the input to track long term trends.  For the longer runs, I include several small and larger sized data sets to allow an approximation of the functions resource requirements.  As with the unit test cases I choose to run the -short version always in the CI and the longer version on a schedule.

---

Whatever your questions are with Go, it is strongly recommended that you try thoroughly reading *both* the https://golang.org/doc/ and relevant https://golang.org/pkg/ documents.  Frequently the most useful documentation is in the package documentation.

Comment: testing.Short() is already a boolean, so testing.Short() == false results in an extra comparison (assuming it doesn't get optimized away by the compiler.  As in your second example, this boolean can be used directly as !testing.Short().