# Only running tests affected by recent changes

Tags: unit-testing, go

Is there a way to executes only those tests which are affected by recent changes in Go? We have a large unit test suite and now it is starting to take a while before it finishes. We are thinking that we only run those tests which are affected by the code changes in the first pass.

Python has something like this: https://github.com/tarpas/pytest-testmon

Is there a way to do this in Go?

Comment: Only package tests are cached: from the test docs: `go test caches successful package test results to avoid unnecessary repeated running of test`

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do it in Go. All you can do is to split your code into packages and tests one package at a time

```
go test some/thing
```

Instead of all of them

```
go test ./...
```

Answer (score 1):

`go test` in Go 1.10 and newer does this automatically at the package level; any packages with no changes will return cached test results, while packages with changes will be re-tested.

If a single package's tests are still taking too long, that points to a problem with your tests; good tests in Go generally execute extremely quickly, which means you probably need to review the tests themselves, and do some combination of the following:

- Isolate integration tests using [build tags](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints). Tests that hit external resources tend to be slower, so making them optional will help speed up runs where you just want unit test results.
- Make use of [short tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238266/7426) so that you have the option of a quick pass you can do more frequently.
- Review your unit tests - do you have unnecessary tests or test cases? Are your tests unnecessarily complex? Are you reading golden files that could be kept in constants instead? Are you deserializing static JSON into objects when you could create the object programmatically?
- Optimize your unit tests. Tests are still code and poor-performing code can be optimized for performance. There are many cases in unit tests where we're happy to opt for convenience over performance in ways we wouldn't with production code, but if performance is a problem, that choice must be reconsidered.
- Review your test execution - are you using uncacheable parameters to `go test` that are preventing it from caching results? Are you engaging the race detector, profiler, or code coverage reporting out of habit in cases where it's unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

[Nabaz](https://github.com/nabaz-io/nabaz) may be what you are looking for.

The example from their README.md is

```
export CMDLINE="go test"
export PKGS="./..." # IMPORTANT make sure packages are written SEPERATLY
nabaz test --cmdline $CMDLINE --pkgs $PKGS .
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use make.
It won't rerun the tests again if there has been no change in the test files.

`` make: `test' is up to date. ``

This is how, you can write the Makefile.

```
# To run commands just use "make" and make function name
# ex- <make run> use for run go run main.go
# Go parameters
execution: echo "** Executing Makefile**"
GOCMD=go

GOINSTALL=$(GOCMD) install
GOBUILD=$(GOCMD) build
GOCLEAN=$(GOCMD) clean
GOTEST=$(GOCMD) test
GOGET=$(GOCMD) get
GORUN=$(GOCMD) run
BINARY_NAME=reservations
BINARY_UNIX=$(BINARY_NAME)_unix

execute:
    - echo "Running the build - reservations"
    - ~/go/bin/reservations-backend

install:
    - echo "Building the module"
    # will create a executable file at $GOPATH
    - $(GOINSTALL)

run:
    - @echo "Running the application - reservations"
    - $(GORUN) $(BINARY_NAME)

#NOTE: @ before a command will stop showing that command.
test:
    - @echo "** Running Tests **"
    - $(GOTEST) -race ./test -v
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot rerun tests only for the last edited files. But there are a few ways of optimizing running tests.
Firstly, you have to split your project into logical-separated packages. This will lead to a situation that one change will require rerunning test only in the package (in most cases).
Secondly, you can run the test only for the package you're changing by typing

```
go test mypkg
```

or... you can use [build tags](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/customizing-go-binaries-with-build-tags). The last way of optimizing is to use the `short` [test functionality](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Skipping).